# Materialize Design

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, materialize, form-fields

Is it possible to change the view of materialize form input field design?

I want to change materialize input field into the bootstrap field that is mention in the image. 
This is the image that actually I want. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uJDd.png)

```
<div class="input-field col s2">
    <input style="font-weight: bold;" id="yearfrom" name="yearfrom"
          value="${parts.yearfrom}" type="text">
    <label for="yearfrom"><strong>YearFrom</strong></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: How is it possible ? will you please give me a demo . #Michael Coker

Comment: You need to give it a shot and let us know what you're having trouble with.

Comment: i already upload a image in my question will you please check it . and i upload  the code that am using .

Comment: I just want to change the field design . will you please check out the image .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the SASS file that has the styles for the input field. Good place to start according to your design is add in the borders around the input field.

Comment: Will you please explain it little bit more.

Comment: Every component in MaterializeCSS is defined in a master sass file. For example, the active color that appears when you click inside an input field has been defined. So if you wanted to change that color, you would need to override it with CSS using the same class name.

Same thing applies to your border, you only have a border-bottom, but from the picture youposted, you want borders on all sides. You will need to override that with CSS. Use inspect element, find out the class names and then add the desired styles.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bootstrap {
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.bootstrap .form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9 !important;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
.bootstrap .form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555 !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075) !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s !important;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s !important;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s !important;
}
.bootstrap label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
Materialize<br><br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <input id="first_name1" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="first_name1">First Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  Bootstrap<br><br>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 bootstrap">
      <label for="first_name2">First Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="first_name2" type="text" class="validate">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I make changings in materialize.css . add border for left right top . but there is no effect in browser .changings not apply when i execute the code .

Comment: browser these days save every thing in the cache so you need to delete your browser cache or open the developer mode and make hard refresh in chrome ctrl +shift + r or right click on the reload button in the top bar. and as you can see it is working in the snippet i made and make sure to add class form-control to the input tag and replace the input-field class by bootstrap class and move the label tag up